# How to get parameter value from URL query string

Tags: javascript

How can I parse the below URL query string to get the value of the quantity parameter?

> myurl/Channels/BuyCredits?quantity=2

I have tried numerous examples without success:

I just tried this example:

```
  marvmentApp.controller("channelCreditController", function($scope, $http, $compile, $location) {
    var params, test2;
    $scope.parseQueryString = function() {
      var objURL, str;
      str = window.location.search;
      objURL = {};
      str.replace(new RegExp("([^?=&]+)(=([^&]*))?", "g"), function($0, $1, $2, $3) {});
      objURL[$1] = $3;
      return;
      return objURL;
    };
    params = $scope.parseQueryString();
    test2 = params['quantity'];
    debugger;
  });
```

I keep getting an error $1 is udefined

Comment: `$0 - $3` only exist within the scope of your empty function `function($0, $1, $2, $3) {}`. (And there are much easier ways to extract a query param.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the JavaScript `location.search` property.  It will return the query string of your URL (including the "?" symbol).

If the URL is `http://www.example.org/index.php?param=arg`

The value `location.search` is `?param=arg`.

To remove the "?", use the JS replace method:

```js
var url = "?param=arg"; // pretend that the variable "url" is the query string
url = url.replace(/[\?]/,"");
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "Query string is: \"" + url + "\"";
```

```html
<p id="output"></p>
```

Hope this helps!